# HTML SPAN tag Stretch to Avaliable Width

Tags: css, width, html

I have the following HTML, with a "span" tag which contains an "input" field and a "span" tag side-by-side:

```
<span class="container">
  <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text">
  <span class="tip">Enter your first name</span>
</span>
```

I would like the child "span" tag to stretch to fill the avaliable area between the right side of the "input" file and the right side of its parent "span" tag. I do not want it to fill the entire area of the parent "span" tag, and, thus, crowd the "input" field. Is that possible with CSS?

Here is my current CSS, if that helps:

```
span.container {
  font-size:14px;
  border:1px solid #22C3EB;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width:200px;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:11px 10px 11px 0px;
}

span.tip {
  position:absolute;
  top:inherit;
  padding:11px 0px 11px 10px;
  display:none;
}
```

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Comment: Give the span element the `display:block` attribute or `display:inline-block`???  Just thinking off-the-cuff here.

Comment: Why do you use a `<span>` tag styled with `display: block;`? Is `<div>` *really* that hard to type in? It's one character shorter than `<span>` (two if you count both tags)!

Comment: @Yzmir, not quite. I manipulate this via jQuery, and by default, it has to be display : none.

@Blender Trying the <div> idea...

Comment: Hmm... the <div> threw the <span> down below. :(

Comment: Gah... sorry people. Guess my mind id tired. Removing the "inline-block" took care of the misplaced <span> tag. And, yes, wrapping this inside of a div took care of it. Thanks, Blender and Yzmir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pramendra/CmgvE/1/

```
span{

}
span span{
    width:100%;
    background:#f00;
    display:inline-block;    

}
span input{
    float:left;
}


<span>
    <span>
        <input type="text" /> 
    some text
    </span>
</span>
```